# Nvidia GeForce 7100 GS drivers on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia-geforce

I have this old computer with this graphic card and I installed Ubuntu because it is lighter than Windows systems but I cant watch videos fluidly.

So I tried to install the propietary drivers of nvidia (304, 331...) and no one appears to work. 
Every time I install one of this drivers I get black screen after log in so I have to uninstall nvidia* and reconfigure xserver.

So, there is any solution?

Comment: Not about the drivers, but if you get a less resouce consuming desktop environment (such as Xfce from Xubuntu) you'll have a much more fluid experience. You won't regret it.

Comment: @EduardoCola Not relevant in this case.

Comment: @ssoomm07 You may want to try nvidia-304 again, and add make sure to run `nvidia-xconfig`. If that doesn't help, try booting with the `nomodset` option. Note: [nvidia-331](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-331.13-driver.html) does not have support for GeForce 7xxx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to nvidia, you are supposed to be using driver 304.

First, purge any existing configuration:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then, install the correct driver:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304
```

Answer (score -1):

In the terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T to open it or Ctrl+Alt+F1) run this

```
 sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
 sudo reboot
```

This will remove any installed nvidia drivers.

Then install the new drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

361 is the latest version of nvidia graphics and it should properly. try this

Comment: ...nice try, except [nvidia-361](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/97759/en-us) does not support GeForce 7100. Those old cards are supported by the legacy nvidia-304 driver.

Comment: @mikewhatever Even the 304 driver is not guaranteed to work well. I would stick with nouveau for this type of cards.